# My hamburger menu doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

My hamburger menu doesn't seem to work. When I click on the hamburger icon itself nothing happens. I have used this exact same code before and it works perfectly fine there. The menu items just slide open when I click on the menu. I have a feeling that I'm doing something wrong with giving the javascript code the right Classes/ID's. But I'm not really sure.

Does anyone have a clue of whats wrong?

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Stefan's menu's - 2</title>
    <link href="main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="hamburger.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
        <div id="hamburger-menu">
           <div class="icon">
            <div class="bar1"></div>
            <div class="bar2"></div>
            <div class="bar3"></div>
            </div>
         <ul id="menu">
            <li><a>Home</a></li>
            <li>
               <ul class="submenu">
                  <li><a>Submenu</a></li>
                  <li><a>Submenu</a></li>
                  <li><a>Submenu</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
               <ul class="submenu">
                  <li><a>Submenu</a></li>
                  <li><a>Submenu</a></li>
                  <li><a>Submenu</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
               <ul class="submenu">
                  <li><a>Submenu</a></li>
                  <li><a>Submenu</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
         </div>
      </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 6px 0;

}

.icon {
    width: 35px;
    margin: auto;
}

ul#menu > li {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
ul#menu > li > ul.submenu {
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid #FF6347;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul#menu {
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;

}

ul#menu a {
    display: block;
    padding: 1em; /* met 1em word de ruimte tussen de list items 2x zo groot */
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #FF4136;
    text-decoration-line: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.submenu {}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.icon').on('click', function () {
        $("#menu").slideToggle();
    });
    $('#menu a').on('click', function() {
        $(this).siblings('.submenu').slideToggle();
    });    
});
```

Comment: It's working in the stack snippet.

Comment: Do you really have the `<script>` to import jQuery *outside* the `<html>` content? I mean that might work but it's kind-of weird.

Comment: `$(this).siblings('.submenu').slideToggle();` will never work. The `.submenu` elements are not siblings of `#menu a` elements.

Comment: @Pointy I added that when I converted his code to stack snippet, it's the snippet boilerplate.

Comment: @Pointy I think stack snippet removes things like `<html>` when it embeds the snippet into the page.

Comment: @Barmar well yea it works here, but I was just curious. You see a lot of stuff here but that's unusual.

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: @Barmar How can I fix that? How are they related to eachother? And I find it pretty weird that the code works here and not with the Brackets live preview.

Comment: Yes:
hamburger.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at hamburger.js:1

Comment: That means you forgot to load jQuery before your script.

Comment: You can do `$(this).closest(".submenu").siblings(".submenu").slideToggle()`.

Comment: Yup, that did it!

I loaded jQuery and used your code and I works!

Thanks!